# KendoUi dropdownlist : how to select text instead index

Tags: kendo-ui

How i could select datatext field instead index

the following select the index instead the datatext field

```
var hhProduct = $("#ProductData").data("kendoDropDownList").select();
```

Please advise how i can achieve this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get or set text of a dropdown you have to use `$("#ProductData").data("kendoDropDownList").text();`